# Elixir Phoenix helper for associated model list

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an app in which I list parents and children. When I add a child, I need to get a list of parents to be shows as a drop list. Is there something like a `collection_select` in Rails available in Phoenix? I would like to display the name of the user and use user_id as a param.

I also want to scope the list of parents by site_id.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [select/4](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4) function from `Phoenix.HTML.Form`.

In your controller you can fetch fetch the parents with a query:

```
query = from(p in Parent, select: {p.id, p.name})
parents = Repo.all(query)
```

The reason we need this query is to format the values in the expected format:

> Values are expected to be an Enumerable containing two-item tuples (like maps and keyword lists) or any Enumerable where the element will be used both as key and value for the generated select.

You can then use `select/4` in your template:

```
<%= select f, :parent_id, @parents ,class: "form-control" %>
```

You can also transform the records using Enum.map/2 if you already have the parents:

```
parents = Repo.all(Parent) |> Enum.map(&{&1.id, &1.name})
```

Comment: Thanks @Gazler, seems like i had to select the name column first in the tuple to get the droplist to display names instead of ids.

Comment: I would use `parents = Repo.all from p in Parent, select: {p.name, p.id}` instead of getting a bunch of stuff you don't need and mapping it after

Answer (score 2):

#### controller

```ruby
all_parents = Repo.all from p in Parent, select: {p.name, p.id}
```

#### eex

```
<%= select f, :parent_id, @all_parents %>
```