# Is it possible to use a Phoenix.HTML select form helper and populate from the ecto data?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I know the Form Helper for lets say `text_input` you pass the atom of the field from the schema and then in the `new` form it will provide an input box and in the `edit` form the input box will be populated.

However, can you do the same thing with the `select` form helper?

I have a schema `Foo` that has a `bar_id` which is a reference to a `Bar` and I would like in the `Foo` PhoenixHTML form to show a select dropdown of all the `Bar` fields.

And then in the edit form the select box to show the selected `Bar` that was previously saved.

But the option value needs to be the `bar_id` from the list of `Bar` items (using another field from the `Bar` schema as the option text)

Is this possible with PhoenixHtml? Or do I have to do something custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the solution to this issue

[Elixir Phoenix helper for associated model list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102960/elixir-phoenix-helper-for-associated-model-list/34104993#34104993)

There is no way of using select without custom stuff